# fallback route to drop packets if output interface that is NATed to goes down?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

**Background:**

I establish a connection to a 3rd party VPN and NAT packets marked as part of a particular cgroup (in order to selectively run processes through the VPN or not) to the 3rd party's VPN tun device (tun2 in this example) and using a route-up script set the default gateway to be the VPN's for a separate route table called 'vpn'. That all works with the following (some minor details are omitted).

**run at boot up:**

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -j MARK --set-mark 11
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -o tun2 -j MASQUERADE
ip rule add fwmark 11 table vpn
```

**contained in openvpn client.conf:**

```
route-noexec
route-up /etc/openvpn/3rdparty/routeup.sh
```

**and routeup.sh to set default gateway for route table vpn**

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/ip route replace default via $route_vpn_gateway dev $dev table vpn
```

**Problem:**
If the 3rd party VPN's interface (tun2) goes down (e.g. openvpn crashes), there is no longer a default route in the route table 'vpn' and all traffic (even that which is run within my separate cgroup) gets routed through the main table and through the default eth0 interface. So I need to set a fallback route in either the iptables or the separate 'vpn' route table. If I use something like,

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -o eth0 -j REJECT
```

it just ends up dropping all packets, so clearly this is processed prior to the nat entry is. Similarly, I can't find a way to use 'ip route' to alter the route table for 'vpn' so that once the default gateway entry is removed after the tun2 interface drops it blocks all traffic. Instead there isn't any entry and it appears all traffic just goes to the next routing table, which must be main.

UPDATE: I've now come up with a complete solution to the problem of selectively running process through a VPN.

https://serverfault.com/a/766290/345463

Comment: It seems openvpn has option `down` config option which enables you to execute script when connection is down. You can use to add your iptables `REJECT` rule.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I ended finding a solution using the 'metric' parameter in routes. I'll post below.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this to work using the metric parameter with iproute2. So my route-up script was modified to the following

```
#!/bin/bash

/sbin/ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway dev $dev metric 1 table vpn
```

and I make sure to also include a fallback blackhole entry with a higher metric value (lower values take priority) to block all traffic. This could be run at boot up with the other lines I listed in my question.

```
ip route add blackhole default metric 2 table vpn
```

This works great

Comment: Here's a complete solution to selectively running process through a VPN, which includes the routing information from this

[http://serverfault.com/a/766290/345463](http://serverfault.com/a/766290/345463)